# Multiple audio tracks waveforms

Tags: android, audio, soundpool, waveform

I have to reproduce several audio tracks at the same time, and should play/pause/resume everyone individually. Also, I need a waveform from each one of them.

First question, is not possible to make the waveform if the track is streaming, right? As far as I understand you need to have the entire file to generate the waveform.

I was thinking on using SoundPool for the basic operations of reproducing the tracks.
Is there any better option to use in this kind of scenarios? Any third party lib?

Also, any info on how generate the waveforms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can only create a waveform for the audio data you have on hand. If you can pre-load the entire track (or portions of it) you can build the waveform on the fly. Playback will lag behind the actually building of the waveform in a perfect scenario.

Generating waveforms is generally taking the samples, distilling them down, and drawing the amplitudes appropriately. You won't want 44,100 samples to represent a visual second of sound most likely but 100 samples per second might work. So, for every 441 samples, calculate the maximum amplitude and plot it however you like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Distilling down' should in fact be low pass filtering to just below the Nyquist rate of the bitmapped display you are rendering it into.  

Whilst calculation an average is a low-pass filter, it's fairly crude one.

Comment: No, we are looking for amplitude to plot here. "Distilling down" in this case means taking an over-abundance of samples (44,100 per second) and making it a more reasonable number that can actually be plotted in a view (100 per second in my example).

Comment: yes. That's bona-fide [sample rate conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_rate_conversion).  If you simply average you will get aliasing artefacts.

Comment: right - but this isn't to play - this is for drawing. calculating the maximum sample of every 441 and then plotting that point to draw the waveform works quite well in my experience for apps that do not need to be able to zoom in more than that amount.